# Detect Ajax and set layout null in SailsJs

Tags: ajax, node.js, sails.js

I would implement pajax, i need to check server side if a request is ajax and set the layout to null to return the view without layout.

I know that the req object contain a 'xhr' property. How can i the layout to null automatically?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: i find a solution! See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31571250/4870013

Answer (score 4):

You can check req.wantsJSON object:

```
// True, if the request has a xhr polling origin. (via socket)
req.wantsJSON = req.xhr;
```

Example:

```
if (req.wantsJSON) {
     res.view("yourView", { layout: null }); 
} else {
     res.view("yourView"); 
}
```

Comment: Ok but i must opy this code in all actions. Can i use this code in a "filter" (like ASP.Net) to execute on every request?

Comment: No you can't. Only what you can do is create object "viewConfig" in a "filter", set "viewConfig.layout" property and pass it into controller action.

Comment: Ohhh thanks! That was the answer that i want. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

> you can use do this by detecting request

```
if(!Request.isAjax)
{
   // your code with return Layout
}
else
{
// your code without return Layout
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can check request.headers if it contains HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH.

If HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH has a value of XMLHttpRequest then it is an ajax request.

Example:

```
if (request.headers["x-requested-with"] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    //is ajax request
}
```

Comment: Ok i understand it but i should copy and paste this code in all controller action. Can i resolve this automatically with a filter for example? That execute it's self on every request? If is ajax is set the layout to null for itself.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution! I use a policy to accomplish that result.

My policy:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.xhr) {
    res.locals.layout = null;
  }
  return next();
};
```

And my policy config:

```
module.exports.policies = {
  '*': 'isAjax'
};
```

Work like a charm!